# NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' after upgrading to rake 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

When running any `rake` task I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' for

This was after `bundle update` which pulled in the new version of rake, version `11.0.1`.

```
$ grep rake Gemfile.lock
       rake
       rake (>= 0.8.7)
     rake (11.0.1)
       rake
$ bundle update
$ bundle exec rake db:drop # any rake task
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' for #< Rake::Application:0x007ff0cf37be38>

**Versions**

- Rails 3.2.11
- Rake 11.0.1

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Rake 11.0.1 [removes](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/ed197e56cc626725f02431d909e02e048244488e/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L8) the `last_comment` method which <del>Rails 2.3</del> rspec-core (< 3.4.4) uses. Therefore until/if a patch is released we need to pin rake to an older version in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '< 11.0'
```

then:

```
$ bundle update
$ grep rake Gemfile.lock 
      rake
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    rake (10.5.0)
      rake
  rake (< 11.0)
```

We are now using rake 10.5.0 which still has the `last_comment` method and our `rake` tasks will work again.

**UPDATE**: This has now been fixed in rspec, so the only thing necessary should be updating rspec.

Comment: I have to use `bundle exec` after do this, how to just still use `rake` without the bundle exec??

Comment: Can you clarify your "Rails 2.3" uses comment?  I'm on Rails 4 and a `rake db:create:all` throws this exception.

Comment: @yekta Rails 2.3 expects Rake to have a method called `last_comment`, where in the codebase this is I do not remember. I do not know if Rails 4 also calls `last_comment`. But you could checkout the rails codebase, switch to the Rails 4 branch and grep for "last_comment" in `Rakefile` and `*.task`.

Comment: Rails 2.3 and Rails 4 do not have any call to `last_comment`, although there are references to it in the rails tests, they would not cause this error.  #confused

Comment: @yekta Does you stacktrace for the error tell you where it is called?

Comment: Thanks for the good questions Kris, I just posted an answer which addresses my (the?) root issue.

Comment: @luke rspec 3.5 or greater.

Answer (score 78):

in Rails quick fix can be edit `./Rakefile` (in your app folder)

and add these lines before calling `Rails.application.load_tasks`:

```
module TempFixForRakeLastComment
  def last_comment
    last_description
  end 
end
Rake::Application.send :include, TempFixForRakeLastComment
```

so entire `Rakefile` might look like

```
  require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
  require 'rake'
  require 'resque/tasks'

+ # temp fix for NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment'
+ # remove when fixed in Rake 11.x
+ module TempFixForRakeLastComment
+   def last_comment
+     last_description
+   end 
+ end
+ Rake::Application.send :include, TempFixForRakeLastComment
+ ### end of temfix
+ 
  task "resque:preload" => :environment

  Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Comment: Thanks.  No longer necessary as of Rake 11.1.0

Comment: nice, there goes my 5 minutes of fame :D

Comment: Still getting it with Rake 11.1.1.

Comment: It looks like the removal of `last_comment` [got reverted](https://github.com/ruby/rake/commit/3948349a82a2522f1d8293093164ef395bee542d) and will now be removed in rake 12.0 instead.

Comment: hmmm, I guess by that time most of gems will fix this code dependency

Comment: is there a way to solve this upgrade sanity issue? it seems to happen every time any upgrade happen...

Comment: After upgrade to rake 12.0.0 I started seeing this error. @equivalent8's temp fix worked for me.

Comment: Upgrading to rspec-core-3.5.4 resolved this for me and I was able to remove the monkey patch in this answer.

Comment: Still a great fix if for some reason you just can't upgrade rspec or rake.

Answer (score 29):

Update to the latest `Rspec` gem does the work:

`bundle update rspec-rails`

Comment: Finding my own answer on StackOverflow - **3 Years** Since I've wrote it - Still works like magic :)

Comment: this is not "always" a good solution, this could install a non compatible rspec -rails version, it's better to always specify the verison to use.

Answer (score 22):

Just upgrade the gem `rspec-rails`

Now: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'`

hugs!

Comment: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'` saved my live, thanks a lot!! And i thought that I have something like last_comment inside my code! LOL

Answer (score 20):

This is an [issue in rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/116) that has been addressed already.

The answer by @equivalent8 is a monkey patch and should be avoided.

As @Kris points out, this is an issue isolated to `rake 11.0.1`.  Since @Kris has posted his answer there are new versions of Rake available and ideally you would be able to stay with the times and not be pinned to an old version of rake.  Believe me, I've been there and its not a good idea if you can help it.  Also this is not an issue with Rails 2.3 or any version of rails.

Any Rake `< v11.0.1` or `> v11.0.1 and < v12` will work but this is still a work around and should also be avoided; ideally you'll be able to stay with the times.

Since `last_comment` is being deprecated the dependency itself should be upgraded.  In my case it was `rspec-core` which incidentally only fixed this in [v3.4.4](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/2197).

**The Fix**

Upgrade your dependency to a version which doesn't call `last_comment` but calls `last_description` instead.  Its probably `rspec` and upgrading `rspec-core` to 3.4.4 or greater will fix it.  `rspec-core` < 3.4.4 calls `last_comment`.

If your dependency doesn't have a version which doesn't call `last_description`, be a good citizen and submit a PR to fix it :)