# Rake commands failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I run any rake command like `rake routes` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' for #<Rake::Application:0x007f4873711d40>
/home/aldo/march_rails/phonebook/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

The line of code in my Rakefile that is being referenced is:

```
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

I have tried prepending `bundle exec` and I have tried deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and rerunning bundler but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893584/nomethoderror-undefined-method-last-comment-after-upgrading-to-rake-11/35893941

Comment: Yes this question is a duplicate. That other answer solved my problem.  Should I leave this question for others using the same wording or should i delete it?

Comment: @aldostevens Others would disagree but my preference is to keep yours here to expand the "net" of people finding it. Sometimes people ask the same question in different ways and part of StackOverflow being so great is that there are multiple ways to ask the same question that leads to the same answer. I'll mark it as a duplicate but leave it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoMethodError: undefined method \`last\_comment' after upgrading to rake 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893584/nomethoderror-undefined-method-last-comment-after-upgrading-to-rake-11)