# Rake 12.3 still produces NoMethodError: undefined method 'last_comment'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

[NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' after upgrading to rake 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893584/nomethoderror-undefined-method-last-comment-after-upgrading-to-rake-11)

I have been encountering the problem described in the thread above. To recap, running `rake` produces the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' for #<Rake::Application:0x00000002b15ba0>
```

The consensus in the thread above is that the 'last_comment' method is deprecated in `rake 11` (replaced by 'last_description').

The answers claim the solution is to either pin `rake` to version 10.5 in the Gemfile, which still calls 'last_comment', or upgrade to `rake 12` and `rspec >3.5`, where the dependency has been resolved. I've tried both solutions, and I still get the same error.

**Update**
The `bundle exec` trace suggests that `rake` is using the system gem for `rspec`, which is only 2.9. How do I either upgrade the system gem or get the bundler to recognize the version I've specified in my gem path?

**Gemfile**

```
gem "rake"
gem "rspec", '>= 3.7'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM

remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rspec (3.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-core (3.7.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-support (3.7.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  rake
  rspec (>= 3.7)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

**Versions**

```
ruby 2.3.1
Rails 4.2.6
rake, version 12.3.0
RSpec 3.7
  - rspec-core 3.7.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.7.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.7.0
  - rspec-rails 3.7.2
  - rspec-support 3.7.0
```

**Traces**

When I run `rake`:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:143:in `initialize'
/home/alexander/Documents/Coding/Ruby/learn_ruby/Rakefile:8:in `new'
/home/alexander/Documents/Coding/Ruby/learn_ruby/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

When I run `bundle exec rake`:

```
Gem::LoadError: can't activate rspec (~> 2), already activated rspec-3.7.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:404:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/home/alexander/Documents/Coding/Ruby/learn_ruby/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

When I just run `bundle`:

```
Using rake 12.3.0
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using diff-lcs 1.3
Using rspec-support 3.7.1
Using rspec-core 3.7.1
Using rspec-expectations 3.7.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.7.0
Using rspec 3.7.0
```

When I run `bundle show rspec-rails`, it says that it could not find the gem.

Comment: Perhaps it's not rspec calling `last_comment` now? Can you produce a longer stack trace?

Comment: Updated with the trace

Comment: `rspec-core-2.99.2` would indicate you're using rspec 2.99.2... perhaps you're using system gems instead of bundler? What happens if you do `bundle exec rake`? And `bundle show rspec-rails`?

Comment: Updated with this information

Comment: `bundle exec rake` is what you want to get working - do you have a longer stack trace for that error? And does just bare `bundle` work okay (can you share the output?)? I would guess some other gem is doing `gem 'rspec', '~> 2'` at runtime; whatever gem that is will have to be upgraded

Comment: I've added the `bundle` output - all the versions are the same as when I just do `rspec --version`, except `rspec-rails` is missing. Any idea why it's not there?

Comment: I've also included the bundle trace.

Comment: Ah if this is for a Rails app you should delete `gem "rspec", '>= 3.7'` from your Gemfile and replace it with `gem "rspec-rails"`. Then execute `bundle` to install it, then `bundle exec rake` to run rake. That might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out: the Rakefile specified `rspec ~> 2.9`. Just deleted the version number, bundle updated `rspec` to 3.7, and everything ran smoothly.